# Confused by conflicting autolayout constraints

Tags: iphone, ios7, autolayout, autoresizingmask

I got this crashlog when I click on tabbar tabitem to change viewcontroller:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xdb98e30 h=--- v=--- H:[UIWindow:0xc65c530(320)]>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xdbba9a0 h=-&- v=-&- UITransitionView:0xdb43ab0.width == UILayoutContainerView:0xdb42ef0.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xc680b80 h=-&- v=-&- UILayoutContainerView:0xdb42ef0.width == UIWindow:0xc65c530.width>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x119352f0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc68a2c0.width == UITransitionView:0xdb43ab0.width>"
)

 Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x119352f0 h=-&- v=-&- UIViewControllerWrapperView:0xc68a2c0.width == UITransitionView:0xdb43ab0.width>

 Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Please explain better - What you don't understand. It is auto layout constrains conflict issue, but we can not help you with out understanding what is that you don't understand.

Comment: i cant understand why I am getting this crash...this crash is not occured every time...sme times app got crash due to this...what to do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First, how are you applying these constraints? The most common cause of these conflict messages is adding constraints without ensuring they are the only ones the view has. Have you set the property

> translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO

before trying to set more? Because you are getting this exception at runtime it looks like Xcode has accepted what you are trying to do so you are probably adding constraints in code.

Did you add all of those constraints in the list that are given as conflicting? If so, remove them and replace them one by one to find which one you got wrong.

If you are doing all this in Xcode in what we used to know of as Interface Builder, use the new tools to examine all of the constraints and verify that you have not added constraints that conflict. Xcode can help you here.

If you are adding constraints in code but you have created the view in IB then you probably want to either manage all constraints in IB or you want to set the xib to NOT use autolayout, so that it does not apply constraints that conflict with what you later add.

Comment: so that means...before adding anything to view like label or sub view or tableview, I need to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO. and what do you mean by adding constraint in code? I am not specifying any constraint. I am just adding label or view by code. And if creating label through code is adding constraint then yes I am doing same thing that you have mentioned in last paragraph. I am creating view in IB and then adding component through code.

Comment: Somewhere you have "Use auto layout" turned on. If you are not using addConstraint: or addConstraints: then you're not doing it in code (you would know if you were). So have you tried to resolve constraints in interface builder?

Comment: I had these same exact warnings when presenting a view controller modally, using a custom presentation controller. My view controller is instantiated from a **storyboard**; Apple's documentation seems to suggest that only views created programmatically (i.e., `init(frame:)`) have this flag set to `true`. Apparently, that only applies to **subviews** that you add in Interface Builder, and the view controller's **main view** _also_ has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to `true` by default even when instantiating from a storyboard.